# How to get employees record grouping by their manager's id?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an Employee table like this:-

```
Emp_ID  Emp_Name    M_ID    M_Name
1      John         101    Sourav
2      Alice        101    Sourav
3      Bob          201    Ramesh
4      Mitchell     201    Ramesh
5      Ricky        301    Punta
6      Smith        301    Punta
```

Now this is table I have for Transaction

```
ID  Emp_ID  Generate
1     1       5
2     1       6
3     1       7
4     2       8
5     2       9
6     2       10
7     3       11
8     4       12
9     5       13
```

I want to calculate Rank on the basis of Generate by M_ID(MangerID). I want Output like this(Rank is calculated on the basis of Generate):

```
    M_ID    Rank
    101     1
    201     2
    301     3
```

Here's is what I have tried.

```
SELECT M_ID,RANK FROM(
SELECT M_ID, RANK=(SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(SUM(Generate),0) DESC) FROM Activity GROUP BY Emp_ID)
FROM Employee
GROUP BY M_ID
)A
WHERE M_ID='201'
```

But this haven't worked for me. I know this is very obvious question i'm asking but please suggest me how do I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT
    E.M_ID,
    GenerateTotal = SUM(A.Generate),
    Ranking = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(A.Generate) DESC)
FROM
    Employee AS E
    INNER JOIN Activity AS A ON E.Emp_ID = A.Emp_ID
GROUP BY
    E.M_ID
```